# EntityFramework stop responding after a SaveChanges() call

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

Ok, needind "any" help/ideas i can get on this...

My project is a MVC4 website that, at some point, is trying to insert a new object on the database. The object is being correctly validated, the data is correctly parsed from the view post onto the parameter and everything looks nice, except that, when I call the SaveChanges, the application stop responding and never comes back. I have a breakpoint just after that statement and it just never comes out of the SaveChanges.

I've already changed all my db to a local instance of SQL Server Express so that I could get the logged SQL statement sent to the db. There's nothing wrong with it either (except from the fact that there's a ROLLBACK at the end, but the .NET don't take any action at all - no exception, no nothing), check out the log of the actions triggered by the SaveChanges:

```
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      ODS Event: Login connection 52
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      ODS Event: Remote_ods : Xact 0 ORS#: 1, connId: 0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Xact BEGIN for Desc: 3400000006
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 0: Name=,Flags=0,Xvt=231,MaxLen=558,Len=558,Pxvar Value=insert [dbo].[Lote]([IDTipoEdificacao], [IDGleba], [IDOutorgante], [Numero], [FracaoIdeal], [AreaAntiga], [AreaNova], [Obs], [DocumentoExtra])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, null)
select [IDLote]
from [dbo].[Lote]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [IDLote] = scope_identity()
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 1: Name=,Flags=0,Xvt=231,MaxLen=156,Len=156,Pxvar Value=@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 nvarchar(20),@4 real,@5 real,@6 real,@7 nvarchar(1000)
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 2: Name=@0,Flags=0,Xvt=56,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=3
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 3: Name=@1,Flags=0,Xvt=56,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=1
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 4: Name=@2,Flags=0,Xvt=56,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 5: Name=@3,Flags=0,Xvt=231,MaxLen=40,Len=2,Pxvar Value=1
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 6: Name=@4,Flags=0,Xvt=59,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 7: Name=@5,Flags=0,Xvt=59,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 8: Name=@6,Flags=0,Xvt=59,MaxLen=4,Len=4,Pxvar Value=0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      Parameter# 9: Name=@7,Flags=0,Xvt=231,MaxLen=2000,Len=8,Pxvar Value=Obs1
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52          IPC Name: sp_executesql
2012-11-28 16:46:43.10 spid52      ODS Event: execrpc : Xact 3400000006 ORS#: 1, connId: 0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.40 spid52      ODS Event: Remote_ods : Xact 3400000006 ORS#: 1, connId: 0
2012-11-28 16:46:43.40 spid52      Xact ROLLBACK for Desc: 3400000006
```

Comment: If there is a rollback it seems like an exception that is not surfaced...

Comment: @Pawel, yes, but still, this is a very strange thing cause if there's an exception (or if there's none) the SaveChanges method should return (one way or the other, which means, propagating an exception or just finish its processing). But the Framework is just there sitting and waiting for something that i can't figure out what it is...

Comment: It's hard to tell. What I would do I would set the VS to break when CLR exceptions are thrown and run your app under the debugger to see if there is an exception and what is it. To do this Debug->Exceptions and check the checkbox in "Thrown" column on the Common Language Runtime Exceptions and start debugging. Other way to trouble shoot this is to debug run this and break manually when it is stuck using the Pause button (Ctrl+Alt+Break) - next to stop debugging button. If it is really stuck in one place the stack trace will tell you method it is stuck in.